# Adding all numbers before a specific index in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
user_list = list(input('Enter a list of numbers'))
    for i in range (len(user_list )):
        user_list [i] = int(user_list[i])
        print(user_list)

first_number = user_list [0]
second_number = user_list [0 + 1]
new_list = []
for i in range (len(user_list )):
    if i == 0:
        first_number = user_list[0]
        new_list.append(i)
    else:
        sum(user_list[:i + 1])
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

This is a code that is supposed to take a list of numbers and return the cumulative sum; that is, each element of the new list is the sum of it plus all the elements before it in the old list.
However, I don't know how exactly does this code work, and I want to make it add the previous indices and add them to a new list.

Comment: Kindly correct the indentation.

Comment: `numpy.cumsum(A)` should do exactly what you want... i think (tbh im not exactly sure what you want)

Comment: `[sum(user_list[:i+1]) for i in range(len(user_list))]`

Comment: @JoranBeasley or `itertools.accumulate` if you don't want to wade into `numpy`

Comment: I edited the code, please check what I did, I still didn't get to what I want.